# commandLink action in p:panelGrid not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, commandlink

I got a panelGrid with command Link nested inside.
I just can't find my mistake.
The action of the command Link is never invoked.
The navigation-case is defined correctly in faces-config.

Some help would be great!

Here is my jsf code

```
  <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{patientsBean.filterEnabled or patientsBean.foldersEnabled}"
styleClass="folderfilter">

<p:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputText value="#{bundle.filter}" />

  <p:selectOneMenu id="filtermenu" styleClass="selectOneMenuFilter" value="#{patientsBean.selectedFilterId}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{patientsBean.filterEntries}" var="filter" itemLabel="#{filter.displayName}"
      itemValue="#{filter.id}" />
    <p:ajax update="patienttable,patientcount, foldermenu" event="change" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid columns="3">

  <h:outputText value="#{bundle.folder}" />

  <p:selectOneMenu id="foldermenu" styleClass="selectOneMenuFilter" value="#{patientsBean.selectedFolderOID}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{patientsBean.readableFolders}" var="folder" itemLabel="#{folder.name}"
      itemValue="#{folder.chilioid}" />
    <p:ajax update="patienttable,patientcount, @this, filtermenu" event="change" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
  <p:commandLink title="#{bundle.tooltipEdit}" action="navFolderManager" style="margin-left: -11px">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" />
  </p:commandLink>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Hi,  please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question accordingly

Comment: Do you have a form tag?

Comment: I still didn't get it :( the action is  invoked now when i put a ?faces-redirect=true instead of the navigation case... but i don't really understand why... 

I got one form tag around all of this.. but no nested forms...